# Sauerkraut crock has a brownish spotting on the exterior and the kraut is making juice. Is kraut going to be ok?

Tags: sauerkraut

I started my kraut in a 3 gallon crock 3 days ago.

There is a brownish spotting on the exterior of the crock.

I checked the kraut and it is making juice.

Do you think the crock is exposing the kraut to air?

The crock itself is damp, but when I set it on a pan, there is no leakage.   Do you think the kraut will be ok?

Comment: Some pictures would be helpful. When you say the kraut is making juice, do you mean it is releasing liquid? It needs to stay covered. in theory your crock could have a slow leak but stay covered and still be OK.